# Linear recursive sequence in closed-form function

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I've been trying to find an answer for a question for some time, and I've done some Google searching but can't seem to figure out exactly how to solve it. It is a linear recursive sequence, and it should be written in a closed-form function.

> Problem:
>
> Find the closed form solution for $R_n = -R_{n-1} + 2R_{n-2}$ when $R_0=3$ and $R_1 = 2$

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: $\lambda^2=-\lambda+2 \Leftrightarrow \lambda=1, \lambda=-2$, so $R_n = C_1\cdot 1^n+C_2\cdot (-2)^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
R_n + R_{n-1} - 2R_{n-2}=0 $$
Let $R_n = \alpha^n$, then 
$$\alpha^2 + \alpha - 2 = 0 \implies \alpha = 1 \text{ or } -2$$

$R_n = A + B\cdot(-2)^n$

Plug in $R_0=3, R_1=2$:
$$
A+B=3
\\A-2B=2$$

Then the desired closed form is 
$$
R_n = \frac{8}{3} + \frac{1}{3} (-2)^n $$

Comment: So would this be the full answer?

Comment: Yes, it is the closed-form solution the question asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$R_n+2R_{n-1}=R_{n-1}+2R_{n-2}\iff S_n=S_{n-1}$$
where $S_n=R_n+2R_{n-1}$. Since $S_n=S_1=8$, one has
$$8=R_n+2R_{n-1}\iff R_n-\frac 83=-2\left(R_{n-1}-\frac 83\right)=\cdots=(-2)^n\left(R_0-\frac 83\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty R_n z^n.$$ Multiplying the recurrence by $z^n$ and summing over the values of $n$ for which it is valid, the left-hand side is
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty R_n z^n = f(z) - R_0 - R_1z = f(z) -3 -2z, $$
and the right-hand side is
$$ \begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty -R_{n-1}z^n +\sum_{n=2}^\infty 2R_{n-2}z^n &= -z\sum_{n=1}^\infty R_nz^n + 2z^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty R_nz^n\\
&= -z(f(z)-R_0) +2z^2f(z)\\
&= f(z)(2z^2 - z) + 3z.
\end{align*}
$$
Equating these yields
$$
f(z) - 3-2z = f(z)(2z^2-z) + 3z
$$
and hence
$$\begin{align*} f(z) &= \frac{3+5z}{1 + z - 2z^2}\\ &= \frac{3+5z}{(1-z)(1+2z)}.  \end{align*}$$
By partial fraction decomposition we obtain
$$ f(z) = \frac83\left(\frac1{1-z}\right) + \frac13\left(\frac1{1+2z}\right), $$
and recognizing this as the sum of two geometric series:
$$ f(z) = \frac83\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n + \frac13\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2z)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac83 + \frac13(-2)^n\right)z^n.$$
It follows that
$$ R_n = \frac83 + \frac13(-2)^n.$$